# How do I find Constructors and needed inputs for JAVA class?

Tags: java, variables, constructor, args

I'm trying to see what constructors and input args need to be present to properly initialize a java object.

I do not have access to plain text .java file only the compiled .class.

I've tried the below code but when I run any of the example commands found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorLocation.html).
Nothing prints out or I get a bunch of exceptions.   The exceptions look to be thrown because nothing was found.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class ConstructorSift {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            Class<?> cArg = Class.forName(args[1]);

            Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
            Constructor[] allConstructors = c.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for (Constructor ctor : allConstructors) {
                Class<?>[] pType  = ctor.getParameterTypes();
                for (int i = 0; i < pType.length; i++) {
                    if (pType[i].equals(cArg)) {
                        out.format("%s%n", ctor.toGenericString());

                        Type[] gpType = ctor.getGenericParameterTypes();
                        for (int j = 0; j < gpType.length; j++) {
                            char ch = (pType[j].equals(cArg) ? '*' : ' ');
                            out.format("%7c%s[%d]: %s%n", ch,
                                "GenericParameterType", j, gpType[j]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // production code should handle this exception more gracefully
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a java programer.  Thanks!

Comment: use javap command. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Comment: If you have an IDE, you can get tab-completion even for compiled classes without source.

Comment: If you're using a class without Javadoc, you shouldn't be.

Comment: @HackerGK WIN. Go ahead and answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) command in the Java tool set.